# Anchor href Routing not working for Downloading a View into pdf

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-snappy

I am using laravel-snappy when i route to the controller for the download using the anchor tag href.

```
" <a href="{{ route('generate-pdf',['download'=>'pdf']) }}">Download PDF </a>"
```

It goes to

```
http://localhost:8000/%7B%7B%20route('generate-pdf',['download'=%3E'pdf'])%20%7D%7D
```

Router:

```
Route::get('generate-pdf', 'PdfGenerateController@pdfview')->name('generate-pdf');
```

Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PDF;
class provider extends Controller
{
    public function generate_pdf() {

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('welcome.blade', $data);
return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
}"
```

Is this the right way to use the laravel-snappy? to download a view?

Comment: Can you show more of the view file? Also, is the view file a `.blade.php` file?

Comment: No, the view doesn't have a .blade. I don't have much on the view just this anchor and a bootstrap grid. I just want to test if the grid is working for the laravel snappy. As I tried DOMPDF but it's not using Bootstrap grid and Font-Awesome symbols.

Comment: You won't be able to use `{{ }}` if it's not a `.blade.php` file.

Comment: Yes, when I rename the file it's working. Thanks, man. But it's not using the bootstrap grid or the font awesome. Do you have any idea how to make it work?? I tried different plugins but none worked.

Comment: I've never used `Snappy` so I have no idea. I did just find this though https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/issues/56 . I would suggest opening another question as it goes outside the scope of this one.